# format excel column to show decimal places end by zero VB

Tags: excel, vb6

I have below vb6 code sending data to excel sheet with one number column formatted to show two decimal places ,everything is working fine except when the decimal number end with zero the excel show only one decimal place like 234.60
showing 243.6 how I can manage to show the zero

```
    Private Sub Command41_Click()

    Dim cno
    Dim tex
    Dim VatAmount As Double
   Dim MyexceL As Excel.Application
   Set MyexceL = New Excel.Application
 Set MyexceL = New Excel.Application
MyexceL.Workbooks.Add
MyexceL.Cells(1, 1).Value = "THC VAT Invoices "
MyexceL.Cells(2, 3).Value = "D/O No. "
MyexceL.Cells(2, 4).Value = "Date "
MyexceL.Cells(2, 5).Value = "Clearing Agent "
MyexceL.Cells(2, 6).Value = "VAT "



tex = App.Path
tex = tex + "\delivery.mdb"
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
con.CursorLocation = adUseClient
con.Open " Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=contianersbakatl;Data Source=ACC-PC\SQLEXPRESS"
con.Execute "DELETE FROM MASTLOT"
'If Option1.Value = True Then
Dim Fdate, sdaTE
Fdate = Format(TXTDAte.Text, "mm/dd/yyyy")
sdaTE = Format(txtdate1.Text, "mm/dd/yyyy")


Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "select * from delivery where  del_date between '" & Fdate & "' and ' " & sdaTE & "' order by del_date ,DEL_sERIAL   ", con, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic


 cno = 0

ccn = 2
While Not rs.EOF

cno = cno + 1
ccn = ccn + 1
MyexceL.Cells(ccn, 3).Value = rs!del_serial
MyexceL.Cells(ccn, 4).Value = CDate(rs!del_date)
MyexceL.Cells(ccn, 5).Value = rs!DEL_CLEARNAME
VatAmount = rs!del_discount * 100 / 117 * 17 / 100 

    MyexceL.Cells(ccn, 6).Value = Format(VatAmount, "#,##0.00")
    rs.MoveNext
    Wend
    MyexceL.Visible = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: I think you mean "VBA" right?

Comment: @ashleedawg - it's VB6...

Comment: i mean visual basic 6 to generate and load data to excel file

Comment: you mean to format excel column/cell after getting the result from vb code

Comment: I stand corrected -- I'm not sure I've ever seen anyone using VB6 to manipulate Excel (not that it's very different from VBA!)

Comment: @TimWilliams yes perfect it's working fine i can accept it as answer .thank you alot am grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the cell `NumberFormat` and then populate the `Value`: just formatting the actual value will not do it.

```
With MyexceL.Cells(ccn, 6)
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    .Value = VatAmount
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's **VatAmount** that is the value in question.  Is the Excel file pre-formatted (template, etc?)  When you format the number on this end, that's not changing the formatting of the worksheet itself.

You'll need to changer the **formatting** number of decimal places displayed on the sheet, either in advance, or programmatically.